# Linphone Audio calling not working in API LEVEL 26 android

Tags: android, sip, linphone

I am trying to implement audio calling in android by using EasyLinphone SDK. It is working with targetSdkVersion 23 and higher target version it's not working. My app targetSdkVersion is 27 on play store so I can not downgrade it. 
Please guide me to implement this feature in my app.

https://github.com/forever4313/EasyLinphone

Answer (score 0):

I've checked & built the code with following attribute & it is working properly both for audio call & video call.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Kindly give Camera and Microphone permission (from app info) of your device settings. Hopefully It'll work.